# using an if statement in a for loop for counting rows based on a condition

Tags: r

I was using the data set txhousing from package ggplot2 and added a column to check the relative performance of median values.

```
a <- summary(txhousing$median)
txhousing$cat <- ifelse(txhousing$median > a[which(names(a) == "Median")], "Hi", "Lo")
```

I just wanted to check how many datapoints were categorized as Lo, and wrote this code for it

```
b <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(txhousing)) {
  if (txhousing$cat[i] == "Lo") {
    b <- b + 1
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the error

> Error in if (txhousing$cat[i] == "Lo") { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you don't have `NA`s in your data. `NA=="Lo"` yields the error you are displaying. You can check with `which(is.na(txhousing$cat9))`

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `table`. But yeah you, have `NA`'s in your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as others have pointed out, are `NA`s.

In your loop you can solve this at least a couple of ways.
1: add another condition so that if `cat[i]` is not `NA` and `cat[i]` is `Lo`, then increment.
2: wrap the condition in `isTRUE()`, which returns `TRUE` if `TRUE`, else `FALSE`, no `NA`s.

```
b <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(txhousing)) {
  if (!is.na(txhousing$cat[i]) & txhousing$cat[i] == "Lo") {
    b <- b + 1
  }
}

b <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(txhousing)) {
  if (isTRUE(txhousing$cat[i] == "Lo")) {
    b <- b + 1
  }
}
```

schwantke is of course correct in that a sum over the relevant column is much preferred, and that `table()` should be considered.

The real strength of `table()`, however, is when you want to combine levels. Say you want to know the number of `Lo` and `Hi` per year, or per city

```
(tab.y <- with(txhousing, table(year, cat)))
(tab.c <- with(txhousing, table(city, cat)))

margin.table(tab.y, margin=2)
cat
  Hi   Lo 
3991 3995
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly all you need to do is

```
sum(txhousing$cat == "Lo", na.rm= TRUE)
3995
```

This tells you "how many datapoints were categorized as Lo". If you want to know both, Lo and Hi, you can you

```
table(txhousing$cat)
```